# Inheriting from inner class

Tags: java, class, oop

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        System.out.println("A()");
    }

    public class B {
        public B() {
            System.out.println("B()");
        }
    }
}
class Caller extends A.B {
    Caller(A a){
        a.super();
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Caller as= new Caller(new A());
    }
}
```

Why do we need `a.super()` call in class extending inner class? What does it doing?

Without `a.super()` program does not want to compile.

```
Error:(48, 20) java: an enclosing instance that contains A.B is required
```

Comment: Extending an *inner* class outside the enclosing class is a **very** bad code design. You should rethink the design.

Comment: Editing the question without mentioning the edit in question itself is also not so good.

Comment: What's the purpose of [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39231197/5) adding an incomplete declaration of `C`? It has no bearing whatsoever on the question.

Comment: I rolled that edit back. It took away from the question rather than improving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: because that's how it is specified in the Java Language Specification.

Your class `A.B` is an inner class of `A`. The constructor has a hidden argument of type `A` - the enclosing (outer-class) instance.

You have subclassed `A.B` in your class `Caller`, which is itself not an inner class. But the constructor of the superclass needs this hidden instance of `A` - the outer class instance.

The way in which you pass this in Java is using this `a.super();` syntax.

The Java Language specification defines this in [section 8.8.7.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1):

> Qualified superclass constructor invocations begin with a *Primary
>   expression* or an *ExpressionName*. They allow a subclass constructor to
>   explicitly specify the newly created object's immediately enclosing
>   instance with respect to the direct superclass (§8.1.3). This may be
>   necessary when the superclass is an inner class.

Answer (score 5):

`a.super()` **does not** call the `A` constructor.  The `A` constructor runs as a result of the expression `new A()` in `Main.main()`.

The `a.super()` invokes the nullary (and only) `B` constructor, specifying `a` as a reference to the containing instance of `A`, which, as a subclass of inner class `A.B`, each `Caller` must have.

Comment: Why `a.super()` invokes the nullary `B` constructor?
Object `a` is an instance of `A`, not `B`! How it determines what constructor need to call?

Comment: @NickNick: Because that's just how this bizarre syntax works. `a.super()` is *fundamentally different* from `obj.method()`. Where `obj.method()` means "call `method` on `obj`", `a.super()` means "call the superclass constructor of this instance being constructed supplying `a` as the outer class reference." (*Should* they have used `x.y` syntax? God no. But they did.)

Answer (score 0):

Error says it all. One of key thing about inner classes (non-static nested ones) is that they have access to its outer (enclosing) instance. But inner class needs to know to which exactly outer instance it belongs. This information is saved in `Outer this$0` reference which is not accessible to us, but it still needs to be set as some point, and that point is code of constructor.

This is why we are creating inner class instances via `outer.new Inner()` like

```
Outer outerInstance= new Outer();
Outer.Inner innerInstance = outerInstance.new Outer.Inner();
//                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thanks to that, outer instance is also passed to Inner class constructor (as hidden parameter).

Now since you are extending inner class, it means that your class will simply specify inner class, but it doesn't mean it stop being of *`Inner`* type.

So since instance of your `Caller` is also considered as `A.B` inner class (since it extends it) you must ensure, that it will have knowledge about its outer instance (of `A` class). To make this possible you in constructor of our class, you need to

1. have instance of your class
2. call constructor of inner superclass `A.B`, so you would let it save that outer class reference in `this$0` variable.

First point is solved by passing A instance as argument of your class constructor `Caller(A a)`.

Second point is done in similar way as calling `outerInstance.new Inner()`, but this time we can't use `new` keyword because we don't want to create new object of Inner class. We want to invoke code from superclass constructor to initialize *current* object (and its hidden `this$0` field properly). Usual way to do it is by calling `super()`. Only thing which could be a bit strange, is that we need to somehow let `super()` call which outer instance is enclosing one. So probably to make it similar to `outer.new Inner()` syntax, we are using `outer.super()` syntax, which in your case is

```
a.super();
```

Answer (score -1):

Since your `Caller` class extends `A.B`, the first call the `Caller` constructor makes will be the `A.B` constructor (even if you don't see it in your code).

So `a.super()` is NOT calling the `A.B` constructor.

Comment: Why a.super() doing nothing?

Comment: Without `a.super` program does not want to compile.

Comment: Getting downvoted because the original question changed is always fun, right @Scadge?

Comment: Well you say that `a.super()` is not calling the superclass constructor `A.B`, which is wrong, because `a.super();` *does* call the superclass constructor `A.B`, and it passes the outer class instance to it. That question was in the first version of this question. So I don't think the change to the question had any effect on the accuracy of your answer.

Comment: There was no version of this question for which this was the correct answer. No shame in that, this is some *truly bizarre* edge syntax in Java.

Comment: If that was true, wouldn't `B()` be called twice? Once from `a.super()`, and once from the implicit super constructor call?

Comment: @AdamRosini Can you explain what you mean by "and once from the implicit super constructor call"? When we already explicitly put `super()`, what is the point for compiler to add any implicit super calls more?

Comment: Ah I see in Eclipse that `a.super()` means `A.B.B()`.

Answer (score -2):

It's not `a.super()` calling `A.B` constructor, but rather `Caller()` constructor calls it implicitly, since `Caller extends A.B`. Only after that the `a.super()` line is executed.

Comment: Nope.  `Caller` extends `A.B`, not `A`, so its constructors invoke constructors of `A.B`, not of `A`.  `A.B` extends `Object`, so *its* constructors don't invoke `A`'s constructors either.  `a.super()` in fact *does* invoke the constructor of `A.B`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I wasn't saying that `Caller()` invokes `A`'s constructor, please read my answer again. Also, the original question was "Why `a.super()` calls `A.B` constructor", and my answer explains that it doesn't.

Comment: @Scadge But it *does*, and that's why your answer is wrong. And Adam Rosini's answer too.